# React react-router-dom private route not working when auth token is asynchronously loaded from cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have a react/redux app, using 'react-router-dom' for routing. I am using the following in my App.js (tags are react-bootstrap, in order to provide private routes. Expected behaviour is to be redirected to `/login` if, and only if, the user is not logged in (based on the presence of a cookie). Actual behaviour is that the app immediately redirects to `/login`, even when the user is logged in.

```
class MainContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.loadAuthCookie();
  }

  PrivateRoute = ({ component: ChildComponent, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => {
          if (!this.props.auth.loggedIn && !this.props.auth.authPending) {
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
          } else {
            return <ChildComponent {...props} />;
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { PrivateRoute } = this;
    return (
      <Router>
        <Container fluid id="root">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Row className="pageContainer">
              <Col>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/clusters/"
                  component={clusterOverviewScreen}
                />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadAuthCookie: () => {
      return dispatch(loadAuthCookie());
    },
  };
};

const RootContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MainContainer);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The function `this.props.loadAuthCookie` dispatches a redux action which pulls the cookie that contains the auth token (if present), and puts it into the state.
Initial state is

```
{
    "authPending": false
    "loggedIn": false
    "authToken": null
}
```

Which becomes:

```
{
    "authPending": true
    "loggedIn": false
    "authToken": null
}
```

and finally:

```
{
    "authPending": false
    "loggedIn": true
    "authToken": TOKEN
}
```

I am relatively new to react. My *guess* is that by the time the PrivateRoute function runs, the redux action has not yet set the state, and therefore, the PrivateRoute component redirects to the login page. This guess is based on logging `props.auth.loggedIn` in the private route - this returns false, but by the time the login page to which I am redirected has finished loading, the component props state that `this.props.loggedIn` is true.I am not sure how to fix this, though.

Edit: loadAuthCookie action:

```
export const loadAuthCookie = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(AuthReducer.setAuthPending());
  try {
    const cookie = Cookies.get("token");
    if (cookie) {
      dispatch(AuthReducer.setLoginSuccess(cookie));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    dispatch(AuthReducer.setLogout());
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you also share your loadAuthCookie action function?

Comment: Try putting `this.props.loadAuthCookie();` as the first line of render instead of being in the constructor; before `const { PrivateRoute } = this;`

Comment: @Hyetigran Done. That suggestion seems to cause a Maximum depth exceeded error

Comment: That's because the function is called in the constructor, which then gets re-rendered and calls the function again. To call the function only once, you should use the componentDidMount lifecycle method

`componentDidMount() {this.props.loadAuthCookie()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PrivateRoute` looks like it's implemented incorrectly.

It should be designed to 'wait' until either `authPending` becomes `false` or a `loggedIn` becomes `true`.

But in reality it requires both of them to be true for it to NOT redirect to login. So implement to 'wait' if `authPending: true` until `loggedIn:true`.

Here is table of the outcomes.

[image: Possible outcomes]

Also don't use conditions like `!loggedIn && !authPending` where readability is terrible especially when you've been working hours on it. I've over looked this because I can't be asked to comprehend what I'm seeing.

```js
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
        if (this.props.auth.loggedIn) {
            return <ChildComponent {...props} />;
        } else if (this.props.auth.authPending) {
            return <LoadingScreen/> // Or could simply div with text. Not different component
            // Then state updates after x seconds and re-renders
        } else {
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        }
    }}
/>
```

Edit: I actually got the logic wrong, either `authPending & loggedIn` can be `true` to redirect to the child element because of the `!` inverse operator.

```js
function test(first, second) {
    if (!first && !second) {
        console.log('login');
    } else {
        console.log('child');
        
    }
}

test(true, true);
test(false,false);
test(true, false);
test(false, true);
```

output:

```
child
login
child
child
```

See still can't get my head around!;

Answer (score 0):

I think Tony is right; you probably need to call `this.props.loadAuthCookie();` later in the lifecycle of this component.

The constructor is run when (and only when) the component is instantiated; as opposed to when it's mounted or rendered. The constructor is usually called once, and before mounting or rendering.

For this reason, calling `this.props.loadAuthCookie()` might work inside of `componentDidMount` as well, but I'd go with Tony's suggestion and try it in the `render()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this triggers a Maximum update depth exceeded error. I've added my loadAuthCookie code to the question if that helps.

Comment: It sounds like `this.props.loadAuthCookie()` is forcing a render (during the render) to create this endless render loop.

A few things to try:

1. Does the "max update depth" error happen if you move `this.props.loadAuthCookie();` into `componentDidMount() ` instead?

2. You might be able to place a guard before the call to `this.props.loadAuthCookie()` so it skips the function on later renders when the auth cookie is already populated. For instance, wrap the call `loadAuthCookie` in a conditional so it only fires when the cookie isn't present: `if (!this.props.auth.loggedIn) {...}`

Comment: No, it doesn't happen if I move it to componentDidMount, but it exhibits the same behaviour as before. Adding a guard (either in render, or in componentDidMount), made it work, but *only* if the App does not re-render. If I follow a link to a privateRoute, it renders, but, if I go to the url directly (i.e., causing the app to re-render), it continually redirects to /login

Comment: I'm not familiar with the pattern of instantiating a higher-order component in the component where is it used. You might try moving PrivateRoute out of the MainComponent class (preferably to a separate file, using something like `export default PrivateRoute` and `import PrivateRoute from './privateRoute.ts'` in your MainComponent file)...this might make the control flow and application state easier to reason upon.